# c++: Class X has no member named Y

Tags: c++, class

I´ve got this CRac class and it´s giving me some problems with its members.

```
//Definition TAD CRac.hpp

#ifndef CRAC_H
#define CRAC_H

namespace bblRac{

struct Racional{
    int num, denom;
};  

class CRac{
public:
    CRac();
    void read();
    void asignarVal (const CRac& otroRac);
    void write();
    void add(const CRac& otroRac)const;
private:
    Racional rac;
    void simplif();

}; //End of class CRac
} //End of namespace bblrac

#endif
```

In a ccp file I have

```
#include "CRac.hpp"
using namespace bblRac;

void CRac::add(const CRac& otroRac)const{
    CRac res;
    res.num= rac.num + otroRac.num; //line 98
    res.denom= rac.denom + otroRac.denom;
}
```

And when I run it, the output is

```
CRac.cpp:98: error: ‘class bblRac::CRac’ has no member named ‘num’
CRac.cpp:98: error: ‘const class bblRac::CRac’ has no member named ‘num’
CRac.cpp:99: error: ‘class bblRac::CRac’ has no member named ‘denom’
CRac.cpp:99: error: ‘const class bblRac::CRac’ has no member named ‘denom’
```

I have tried to fix it with the pointer this, but it continues giving the same mistake..
Thank you!

Comment: Racional have a member num, not CRac. Maybe you meant `res.rac.num` instead of `res.num`? (same for otroRac.num and rac.num).
Also, the member rac is private, you won't be able to directly access it for the otroRac object, maybe you should add a method getRac().

Comment: `add()` doesn’t make much sense. It creates a `CRac` object, modifies it, then discards it. If you want `a.add(b)` to modify `a`, then `add()` should not be `const`, and you should work on `rac.num`, i.e., `this->rac.num`, not `res.rac.num`. Also, many of these methods would make more sense as operator overloads: `read()` as `friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, CRac&)`, `write()` as `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const CRac&)`, `asignarVal` as `CRac& operator=(const CRac&)`, and `add()` as `CRac& operator+=(const CRac&)`.

Comment: All I want to do with that function is to add up two objects and save the result in another one. I have tried to overload the operator +, but the output is the same: class bblRac has no member named...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fix it.

```
#include "CRac.hpp"
using namespace bblRac;

void CRac::add(const CRac& otroRac)const{
    CRac res;
    res.rac.num= rac.num + otroRac.rac.num; //line 98
    res.rac.denom= rac.denom + otroRac.rac.denom;
}
```

Your `CRac` class contains a `Racional` member variable, `num` and `denom` are not members of `CRac`.

Comment: @CyberDude You can access private `CRac` private members from inside `CRac` member functions.

Comment: This way it doesn´t work either because `res` and `rac` are objects, and I want to access to num and denom (denominator)

Comment: So it continues giving me the same mistake: class bblRac has no member named num and denom

Comment: I doubt you're getting that error since `bblRac` is a namespace. I have just copied your code, pasted it in a file, modified what i stated in my answer and it compiles. Are you sure you have included **the entire method** i provided in my answer? Copy and paste it.

Answer (score 2):

```
res.rac.num = whatever;
otroRac.rac.num = whatever;
```

Please look your code over before you hit copy/paste into StackOverflow.